# PHP - if statements bloated

Tags: php

The user gets several options which adds a different class into something that is read into PHP -

The below works, but it seems very inefficient and uses a lot of code. Is there a way I can cut this down?

```
<?php
    if(get_sub_field('status') == "Upcoming"){
        echo '<li class="upcoming">';
    }

    if(get_sub_field('status') == "Next"){
        echo '<li class="next">';
    }

    if(get_sub_field('status') == "See what happened"){
        echo '<li class="happened">';
    }
?>
```

Comment: You could use a `switch`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The only way you could change it is this:

```
echo '<li class="' . get_sub_field('status') . '">';
```

Otherwise there is no way around this! You have to use `if` and `elseif` or you make a `switch` statement

When you sill want to look if the value is valid you can make a array like a whitelist:

```
$valid = array(
            "Upcoming",
            "Next",
            "See what happened"
         );
```

And then you can check it like this:

```
if($value = array_search(get_sub_field("status"), $valid))
     echo '<li class="' . strtolower($value) . '">';
else
    echo '<li class="default">'; //if something fails
```

Comment: You just completely copied my answer.

Comment: @self And copied `array_search` issue too :)

Answer (score 4):

You could make a table that holds the available values for which you want. This way eliminates all of the if statements. Keep in mind thought that this is functionally equivalent to your code above.

```
$opt_vals = array(
    "Upcoming",
    "Next",
    "See what happened"
);

$val_to_search = get_sub_field("status");

if(($key = array_search($val_to_search, $opt_vals)) !== FALSE) {
     echo '<li class="' . strtolower($val_to_search) . '">';
}
```

Since [`array_search`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) returns the key with the corresponding value, `$key` would hold the key, but as [@Timur](https://stackoverflow.com/users/851548/timur) emphasized, a value at corresponding index 0, would evaluate to FALSE, 0, so in order to really check if it has the value we have to use the strict `!==` operator because `0 == NULL` would evaluate to true.

Comment: If `array_search()` returns `0`, the key of `"Upcoming"`, your condition will be executed as `false` and nothing will be outputed.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it with if...else if like this.

```
<?php
    $status = get_sub_field('status');

    if( $status == 'upcoming')
       $class = 'upcoming';
    else if( $status == 'Next' )
       $class = 'next';
    else if( $status == 'See what happened')
       $class = 'happened';
?>
<li class="<?php echo $class; ?>"></li>
```

Comment: PHP supports `elseif` natively.